# Apply additional access controls to attachments

Tags: trello, attachment, access-control

Is there a way to apply access controls to attachments?

That is, if multiple board members are assigned to a card and someone is uploading an attachment with sensitive information and preferably only the board member and the uploader, or being able to select only certain members, to be able to open the attachment.

Answer (score 1):

> **Features and Ideas**
>
> Just thought of a great idea for Trello? We might already be working on it! We use a public Trello board to develop Trello so you can see, comment, and vote on features. Visit our [Trello Development board](https://trello.com/board/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c).
>
> If your feature isn't there, tell us about it on Twitter! Follow [@trelloapp](https://www.twitter.com/trelloapp) and send a tweet to us about your idea. If your idea won't fit into 140 characters, you can email it to **feature-ideas@trello.com**. We read all feature ideas but may not be able to respond to them individually.

From the [Trello help](https://trello.com/help) page.